# Get versionCode value in gradle from strings.xml in Android Java

Tags: android

I have written below code in **gradle** which works fine for getting the versionName from strings.xml,

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "@string/app_version_name"
}
```

but when I am writing

```
versionCode "@string/app_version_code"
```

It generates below error:

#### Error:

> (11, 0) Could not find method versionCode() for arguments [@string/app_version_code] on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, ..... of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.

```
<a href="openFile:D:\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```